# Is stackoverflow.com for sale?

Tags: discussion

I made a [whois search](http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com) and I found this:

[image: Whois Record for StackOverflow.com: StackOverflow.com is for sale!]

How much do they want? I'm just curious.

Comment: Probably not. How do you not know the company making that listing is 1) lying, 2) just trying to get your money?

Comment: 100 unicorn dollars, obviously.

Comment: You can't see the sign because it no longer is for sale; I just bought it for $400. The domain will be used for E-Mail only, sorry.

Comment: @the_nuts what I mean is that there are a lot of companies that help to negotiate the sale and transfer of a website. I can tell you that my friend's computer is for sale, and I can get your attention that way. Whether it works or not is different.

Comment: And genuine handbags @Pekka웃?

Comment: "Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2015-12-26T19:18:07-07:00Z" I'd hardly say that counts as "available".

Comment: [OK, let's see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1IyrQ.png)

Comment: @the_nuts: no idea who goofed, but Sedo has some 'splainin to do.

Comment: Btw people, this seems to be a reasonable meta post regarding a strange bit of information that may seem to come from a reputable source. I don't really see the need for all those downvotes, however unlikely the sale is.

Comment: Network Solutions says `stackoverflowpro.com` is available. I think I'll start using that one, they sound way more l33t

Comment: @durron597 Is that for anyone who graduates from Stack Overflow?

Comment: @durron597 buy it and redirect all traffic to yahoo answers.

Comment: @gunr2171 Quora, not yahoo answers. ldo.

Comment: Lol I think they have been hacked or they are all drunk https://twitter.com/bartkevelham/status/628307571397500932

Comment: I have not been hacked, nor am I drunk. As disturbing as it may seem, this is my regular behaviour.

Comment: Not your tweet but their two replies :)

Comment: @durron597 Is that Jon Skeet's own Stack Overflow website?

Comment: @Pekka웃 [Sorry!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd48Z.png)

Comment: @DavidG NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Comment: I love how the associated email is "abuse@name.com"

Comment: Everything is for sale, it's just a question of _how much_ ;)

Comment: @Doorknob You mean 100 unicoins? :)

Comment: Its not showing perhaps it was an advertisement which can be anything

Comment: How possibly they can do that without taking permission from Jon Skeet? It is then fake for sure.

Answer (score 95):

It's probably a mistake of some sort: while usually, this kind of "domain is available" advertising leads to spurious "back-order" services that try to grab the domain when it expires, this specific banner leads to sedo.com, generally a reputable company.

It's not in character for them to advertise a multi-million company's domain as "for sale". The most likely explanation seems to be an oversight on their part.

<sub>I'll be filthy rich when my $400 offer goes through!!!</sub>

Comment: It is less than 6 months until the current registration *does* expire so it could be some automatic process that's kicked in and not been vetted.

Comment: @ChrisF hmm, it would really be out of character for Sedo to do stuff like this. They're solid guys, at least used to be.

Comment: I think about half of the domains expire within 6 months since people usually renew them yearly...

Comment: Most importantly, the renewal process is *automatic*. There is usually no chance of grabbing a valuable domain at renewal time.

Comment: Think of all the discount handbags you could sell from that domain.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - which makes me think even more that something's gone wrong with the systems at Sedo. The < 6 month has triggered the "for sale" system rather than the "contact the owner about renewing" system.

Comment: Just renew it now, for like 20 years or whatever the max is to get discount.

Comment: Sedo replied: https://twitter.com/Sedo/status/628309024728031232 All they need is proof of ownership apparently. What made them put it up in the first place is still beyond me.

Comment: Would be a clever marketing campaign. @Bart

Comment: That tweet means they don't think it's listed in error

Comment: @the_nuts they're being stupid. Probably have no idea what Stack Overflow is. Ah well.

Comment: I'm very sorry @Pekka웃 https://twitter.com/Sedo/status/628551489628307456

Comment: @Bart they just E-Mailed me. There will be litigation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Pekka웃 get the website, first increase your points, then turn this website to a handbag store.

Comment: If it is you probably can't afford it ;)

Answer (score 38):

Stackoverflow.com is not for sale, nor is going to be through any public website anytime soon.

*If* the Stack Overflow SRE team *theoretically* had a shadow faction, it would possibly have some [darknet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darknet) auction page, and that would probably be where the domain would be for sale come December, for a lot of bitcoins. And you would have to know someone like Reddington to even find the correct `.onion`.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about but I think I'll keep you on board when Sedo accept my offer (any minute now) and I take over Stack Overflow for $400. You can write my blog posts.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If for some reason your order with Sedo doesn't go through I can sell you Fort Knox for $400 instead. Current inhabitants must be removed by new owner.

Comment: Or you can buy a [nice piece of the moon](http://www.moonestates.com/) for that  :)

Answer (score 11):

It's just a marketing strategy. They will probably advertise every popular domain you search for as "is for sale" to get you to make an offer, so that they can contact the registered owner to ask if they will sell. In fact the banner looks like a paid ad from an external website. When I open the page I see a different banner ad for another service. The link redirects through doubleclick.net

Comment: As shown in previous comments, this was a mistake on the part of Sedo. They have removed SO from their listings.